# How assign struct of a package into another package's struct with same fields

Tags: go, struct

I have a struct in `main` package :

```
package main
type DispatchesDetailsStruct struct{}
```

And I created another struct in package `store` With same fields as of struct created in `main` package.

```
package store
type DispatchesDetails struct{}
```

Here what I'm going to do, I created a function inside `store` package with return `DispatchesDetails` struct.

```
func (s *DispatchStore) GetDispatchByCondition(dispatchObject DispatchesRequestStruct, objRaouteAvailability Availability) (dds []DispatchesDetails, err error) {}
```

Now i call this `store` function from `main` package and assign returned value to `main` package struct but its showing error message

> can not assign store.DispatchesDetails to DispatchesDetailsStruct type.

I'm confused please help me.
Thanks

Comment: From different packages, therefore different structures. Maybe you can type convert them. And please: Take the Tour of Go once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import store package inside your main package. Go is strictly typed language. Here you cannot assign a struct to another struct even if they are similar. Though you can [embed](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) your struct into another.

```
package main
import( 
      "store"
     )

type DispatchesDetailsStruct struct{

}

func main(){
  storedispatchObject := store.DispatchesDetailsStruct{}
  storedispatchObject.value = userDetails.value
  dispatchesList, err := dps.GetDispatchByCondition(storedispatchObject, objRaouteAvailability)
}
```

After above code snippet the DispatchesDetailsStruct will be of store type and you can use it in store function

Answer (score 2):

`main.DispatchesDetails` and `store.DispatchesDetails` are completely different types. You probably want to choose one and use it exclusively.

For example, instead of:

```
package main

details := &DispatchesDetails{ ... }
```

use:

```
package main

details := &store.DispatchesDetails{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Go considers named types different even they have the same structure.

I recommend this way if you need the same type in different structures - **move all types definitions to 3rd package** and import from there.

Thus you solve many issues at once:

1. Every type is defined once. If you need some changes you do them in one place.
2. All definitions are grouped together - easier to find. Package with types will be small.
3. You never run into cyclic imports if you need type from another package.

So you may come to a project structure like this:

```
github.com/user/project/schema  — types
github.com/user/project/user  — some package for users
github.com/user/project/resources  — types
```

Comment: yes thank you Eugene Lisitsky , it will be good to imports but in my case i don't think to create another package to use struct which is used one time in project.

Comment: That’s up to you and your project. Sometimes it’s useful starting with 2or 3 packages making them loose coupled.